# No space left on device google-app-engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine

I can't clone git or upload my web to gcloud and the only one notice I get is 
"error: unable to create temporary file: No space left on device"

What I've tried to do:
1. Restart VM
2. Expanse storage

And its not solved yet. Pls help

Comment: The message typically indicates a filled partition on the system where the command is executed. But your question is way too brad, you need to provide more info: which partition, which machine, etc. Your description of the actions and events is insufficient to determine that. Actual logs with the commands and error messages are highly recommended. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Comment: This doesn't sounds like you are using App Engine. What GCP product are you using?

Comment: Just in case you are using Google Compute Engine instead, I wrote an article yesterday on how to resize a root partition remotely using `gcloud`. https://www.jhanley.com/google-cloud-debian-9-resize-root-file-system/